# Who knew about Delphini's birth?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child, delphini

We don't know much about pregnancy and delivery in the wizarding world but it's likely that witches also need a follow up during when they're pregnant, and at least some kind of help when giving birth.

Was Bellatrix' pregnancy known to any healer (tied or not to medical secret)? Or to anyone?

I'm especially thinking of Narcissa, as she was her sister (and although "family love" is kind of special in this family, the both most of the time got along) and the baby was born at her place; thus she's the most likely person to have known and maybe even helped Bellatrix...

Comment: Voldemort probably.

Comment: Keep in mind that the wizarding world doesn't have much use for modern muggle science. At the time when muggles used (for example) quills, most of their babies were born at home and doctors were only called in the case of complications. It's possible that the present day wizarding world has an equivalent of a midwife who knew the correct spells to use for common problems with childbirth, but I don't believe this is mentioned anywhere,

Answer (score 4):

### People who definitely knew before 2017

**Delphini's mother, Bellatrix and her husband Rodolphus were aware**

> ***Delphi:*** It was Rodolphus Lestrange, Bellatrix’s loyal husband, who on return
>   from Azkaban told me who I was and revealed the prophecy he thought I
>   was destined to fulfill. I am your daughter, sir.

**Euphemia Rowle (probably)**

> ***Delphi:*** She used to say it was crying because it could see I was going to come to a sticky end. She didn’t like me much. Euphemia
>   Rowle . . . she only took me in for the gold.

**Whoever made the prophecy about her**

A recent Pottermore article mentions "[Naming Seers](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/naming-seers)".

> A certain sector of magical society, however, follows the ancient
>   wizarding practice of consulting a Naming Seer, **who (usually for a
>   hefty payment of gold) will predict the child's future and suggest an
>   appropriate moniker.**

And that's pretty much it. There's no indication that Voldemort was aware that he had a daughter.

---

Note that this appears to be a retcon by those that wrote CC since there's no mention in the books (by the Death Eaters who were present at the Malfoy's mansion) of what should have been a visible late-stage pregnancy. This could mean, theoretically, that Delphini's father was simply lying to her about her parentage for reasons of his own.

Comment: Delphini's mother + her husband maybe rather?